# (Win32) Heap shared between processes

Tags: winapi, heap-memory, shared-memory

Is it possible to create a memory pool shared between processes (for example from `CreateFileMapping` with `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in Win32) and then use that chunk of memory as a heap ?

I would like the `new`/`delete` operators (or `malloc`/`free`) to allocate/free memory from that chunk (and do their usual heap management on it).

Thanks.

**EDIT**: My real problem is simple: for now I use the `new` operator to allocate various large series of structures normally, but I want these structures to persist after the process closes. So I would like to create another process whose almost only function is to hold the memory when the main process closes.

For that, I would create a chunk of shared memory with `CreateFileMapping` in the auxiliary process, and, in the main process, tell those `new`/`delete` used to allocate the structures to use that chunk instead of the process's heap.

To recover the structures after the main processes is relaunched, I would add a fixed amount to all the pointers, reflecting the different origins of the mapped view returned by `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: Yes if you implement your own heap manager on top of the file mapping.

Comment: Don't forget the synchronization.

Comment: @Roman my question was precisely how to use the existing heap management logic in malloc/new and not implement it from scratch :)

Comment: @Raymond if you mean using a simple semaphore bool variable shared between the processes, then I won't forget!

Comment: A simple bool variable may not be good enough.

Comment: Concurrent access, mapping to different addresses in different processes, fixed size of underlying mapping - these are things I immediately thought of that you will need to deal with. It is surely possible to implement all this, I just doubt that you can apply any standard heap management onto it.

Comment: @Roman: the heap manager doesn't have to know that the memory chunk is going to be shared. It would only be necessary to tell the heap manager "this is the chunk of memory you are dealing with" and then it applies its logic to it (I deal with the concurrent access problems myself). What difference does it make whether it applies its logic to an existing chunk (fixed size) or it allocates its own one?

Comment: Heap manager can be designed with all this in mind. The opposite however is incorrect: not every well working heap manager is readily available to work on top of supplied chunk. Especially, as I mentioned, if this chunk is mapped into different address on another process.

Comment: This isn't tenable. If you want help with your real problem, tell us what it is.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database. Or you just need to serialize to disk on process close, and then de-serialize when it restarts. Those are the tenable solutions.

Comment: @David I already do, I load a big chunk of a SQL Server database in memory and do things to the data, and I don't want to do that every time I relaunch the process, so I want to preserve the memory... This seems quicker than having to serialize all the data to disk only to preserve the memory.

Comment: You should find a solution to your problem that works. Even if you had a shared heap, which you can't have, it wouldn't actually solve your problem. Calling `new` when your process restarts isn't going to result in memory having the same values as when the process closed. Your problem is one of serialization and not one of sharing.

Comment: @David when the process restarts I wouldn't call new, I would use the existing memory -- I would only add a fixed amount to the pointers to reflect the different origin of the mapped view. And again it's not really a shared heap, it's only asking new to allocate memory from a fixed chunk of memory, which happens to be shared (but new doesn't have to know that).

Comment: @David ah OK I see what you mean: after the process relaunches I wouldn't be able to use `new` again since the heap management data structures are lost, so it doesn't know what parts of the existing memory are already allocated, and what parts are free. So I would have to save the whole memory pool used by that private heap, including the heap data structures, but then the heap data structures would contain the old pointers, and I can't add a fixed amount to those pointers without knowing how these heap structures are organized... So saving a snapshot of a heap seems difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people who commented.

Answering my own question:

I gave up on making the shared memory a heap, I simply save a fixed snapshot of the structures to the shared memory allocated by the other process with `CreateFileMapping`. I just do the opposite when the process is relaunched, using `OpenFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.